# PostgreSQL: Selecting by random ID with strange results

Tags: postgresql, select

I wanted to select random row from table that has `bigint` PK and value (`text` in the example below, I tried to use `UUID` but changed the example to avoid `gen_random_uuid` that is not by default on PG 12):

```
create table xoid (id bigint primary key, oid TEXT);
insert into xoid (select generate_series(1, 100) as id, md5(random()::TEXT) as oid);
```

Now I tried to select random row with the second select from the following block, other selects are there for check:

```
select * from width_bucket(random(), 0, 1, 100);

select * from xoid
    where xoid.id = width_bucket(random(), 0, 1, 100);

select * from
     (select width_bucket(random(), 0, 1, 100) id from generate_series(1,10)) a
    left join xoid on xoid.id = a.id;
```

The strange thing is that the first select always returns one random number and the third select, where I check whether the random number joins with the table always returns 10 rows as expected - and all have OID.

But the key select, the second one, sometimes returns no row - and what is even more funny, sometimes returns multiple rows, 2 or 4. Sometimes it returns one. What is wrong with that select that it does not match the ID in the table? Is it something with `width_bucket`? But why does it always work in the second select? (That one was written to identify the wrong values of `width_bucket`, but obviously I failed. :-))

Available as a fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2mRXT4wGjM2ZSftjgKyZce/36

Tested with PG 12/13.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your second query should always return one value if you do it in this way:

```
select * from xoid
    where xoid.id = (select width_bucket(random(), 0, 1, 100));
```

Comment: Yes, it does. This actually helps, thank you for that. But why?

Comment: @virgo47 It's the way it evaluates the query, I believe. If it's part of a subquery it will run the subquery first and then use that value to compare to each row of the table. If you compare against the function itself, it will calculate a new value on every row and if the value matches the id, it will select it.

Comment: Of course! Now when you say so it's SO obvious! Back to school... thanks, accepted.